# Locally Developing Multiple Microservices

Tags: localhost, microservices

Imagine you have a React front-end (FE) which is interacting with a Python based back-end (BE) of multiple microservices.  So the FE might call an endpoint at BE-A and then later at BE-B and perhaps later at BE-C.  Some pages may need to interact with BE-A, BE-B, and BE-C all at once.

When this is deployed remotely, all works perfectly fine but when working on things locally, is there an easy way to do this with BE-A running in one Terminal session, BE-B in a second Terminal session, and so on?

Note: I'm aware of the local Docker approach but am wondering if there's a simpler way to do it without anything like Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you use with python but I will assume you are using something like flusk.
Lets say you are using flask and you have your scripts for services as micro-service-a.py,
micro-service-b.py and micro-service-c.py. You could run them like this:

**In Linux Bash**

Open a terminal session 1 and run:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=micro-service-a.py

$ flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001
```

Open a terminal session 2 and run:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=micro-service-b.py

$ flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5002
```

Open a terminal session 3 and run:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=micro-service-c.py

$ flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5003
```

This way you will each of your services running in a different port so you can consume each service api from different port on localhost like localhost:5001, localhost:5002 and localhost:5003.

**In Windows Powershel**

The only difference would be that you would set the env:FLASK_APP in a different way. For example:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "micro-service-a.py"

flask run
```

You can read more about the CLI commands [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/cli/).

You can even write some small powershell or bash script to initialize, start the processes, stop and remove them. You don't have to do it manually in all 3 terminal sessions and if you have more micro-services then it would be even more terminal sessions which you will need to manage. That would make your work easier.

---

You can do that sure but instead I would highly recommend using Docker for this purpose. The good thing about docker is that you would create a docker-compose which would have its own network for your environment. This would include all the parts of your application including your ReactApp as one container and a container per micro-service. This way you could even have different python versions in each micro-service and the commands to initialize, build and run, stop, start, remove your whole app would be like:

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose-my-react-and-python-app.yml" up -d

docker-compose -f "docker-compose-my-react-and-python-app.yml" stop

docker-compose -f "docker-compose-my-react-and-python-app.yml" start

docker-compose -f "docker-compose-my-react-and-python-app.yml" down -v
```

> Note: I'm aware of the local Docker approach but am wondering if
>   there's a simpler way to do it without anything like Docker?

Using docker for this is much simpler then writing and managing all those scripts(bash or powerhsell) manually.

You can find a lot of examples how to create Dockerfile and docker-compose files for similar apps as you are building here on Stack-overflow or other sources online.